# Check rows if they contain any text from a range of other rows

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like to check each B row if it contains anything from F1:F619 and E rows should display `draft` if it does and `publish` if it doesn’t.

I’ve looked everywhere in the Google Sheets documentation and everywhere and I cannot find any formula to do that.

[image: 0]

Here is the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_zH5ty4ADUv12eaNgH_16qyYTDRo-LC7g50GfuYklsI/edit?usp=sharing

Video describing the issue:
https://streamable.com/a6u6b

Answer (score 0):

paste in **E1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B1:B), 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(B1:B, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, F1:F)), "draft", "publish"), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

[image: 0]